# change the text of the Label on TableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, segue

I have first view controller (FirstView Controller) on which presents two TextFields and one TableView that include TableViewCell with Label. And I have second view controller (TypeViewController) that also include TableView with TableViewCell that include one Label.

On FirstViewController select TableViewCell with text *Choose* -> go on view TypeViewController

On TypeViewController select TableViewCell (on TypeViewController i have list of cells, that loading dynamically) -> go back to FirstViewController and instead of text *Choose* display the text that was selected on TypeViewController.

**How can I change the text of the Label on TableViewCell on the FirstViewController to text from the TypeViewController?**

**First View Controller**

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var animalTypeName: String?;

    var selectedTypeId: UInt?;
    var selectedTypeName: String?;

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad();
    }

    // MARK: TableView && TableViewCell Methods
    // Row display.
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1;
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! FirstTableViewCell;
        animalTypeName = "Choose";
        cell.typeName.text = animalTypeName;

        return cell;
    }

    //MARK: - Navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)

        switch(segue.identifier ?? "") {
            case "ShowType":
                guard segue.destination is TypeViewController else {
                fatalError("Unexpected destination: \(segue.destination)");
                }
            default:
                fatalError("Unexpected Segue Identifier; \(String(describing: segue.identifier))");
        }
    }

    //MARK: Actions
    @IBAction func unwindToCreateMedicamentController(sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {
        if let typeViewController = sender.source as? TypeViewController, let type = typeViewController.type {

            selectedTypeName = type.name;
            selectedTypeId = type.animalTypeId;
            animalTypeName = selectedTypeName;
        }
    }
}
```

**TypeViewController**

```
import UIKit

 class TypeViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var typeList: [AnimalType]?;
    var type: AnimalType?;
    let typeController = AnimalTypeController();

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad();
        // Call method to get array of AnimalType items.
        getArrayOfTypeItems();
    }

    //MARK: - Table view data source
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1;
    }

    // Row display.
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return typeList?.count ?? 0;
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    // Table view cells are reused and should be dequeued using a cell identifier.
    let cellIdentifier = "TypeTVCell";

    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? TypeTableViewCell  else {
        fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of TypeTVCell.");
    }

        let typeItem = typeList?[indexPath.row];
        cell.nameOfType.text = typeItem!.name;

        return cell;
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)

        switch(segue.identifier ?? "") {
        case "ChooseType":
            guard segue.destination is CreateMedicamentController else {
                fatalError("Unexpected destination: \(segue.destination)");
            }

            guard let selectedTypeCell = sender as? TypeTableViewCell else {
                fatalError("Unexpected sender: \(String(describing: sender))");
            }

            guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: selectedTypeCell) else {
                fatalError("The selected cell is not being displayed by the table");
        }
            let selectedType = typeList?[indexPath.row];
            type = selectedType;

        default:
            fatalError("Unexpected Segue Identifier; \(String(describing: segue.identifier))")
        }
    }
}
```

[image: This`s an example of my views]

Comment: you need to set delegate.

Comment: This must be one of the most common iOS questions on SO. https://medium.com/@jamesrochabrun/implementing-delegates-in-swift-step-by-step-d3211cbac3ef

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var animalTypeName: String?;

    var selectedTypeId: UInt?;
    var selectedTypeName: String?;

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad();
        animalTypeName = "Choose";
    }

    // MARK: TableView && TableViewCell Methods
    // Row display.
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1;
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! FirstTableViewCell;
        cell.typeName.text = animalTypeName;

        return cell;
    }

    //MARK: - Navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)

        switch(segue.identifier ?? "") {
            case "ShowType":
                guard segue.destination is TypeViewController else {
                    fatalError("Unexpected destination: \(segue.destination)");
                }
            default:
                fatalError("Unexpected Segue Identifier; \(String(describing: segue.identifier))");
        }
    }

    //MARK: Actions
    @IBAction func unwindToCreateMedicamentController(sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {
        if let typeViewController = sender.source as? TypeViewController, let type = typeViewController.type {

            selectedTypeName = type.name;
            selectedTypeId = type.animalTypeId;
            animalTypeName = selectedTypeName;

            tableView.reloadData();
        }
    }
}
```

1. Move `animalTypeName = "Choose";` to `viewDidLoad`.
2. Add `@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!` in `FirstViewController`
3. Add `tableView.reloadData()` in `unwindToCreateMedicamentController(sender: UIStoryboardSegue)`

Answer (score 1):

In the `viewDidLoad` method**s** you need to add the folowing code:

```
tableView.dataSource = self
tableView.delegate = self
```